# IllegalAccessError to method copyOfRange Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, illegalaccessexception

I have an issue when I try to run my project, the situation is:

I have updated Android Studio from **3.2.1** Stable --> **3.3** Stable

I have updated Kotlin Plugin from **1.2.71** Stable --> **1.3.11** Stable

obviously before the update the project synchronized correctly, but now it show this error:

```
    > Task :compileAospDebugKotlin
Compilation with Kotlin compile daemon was not successful
java.lang.Exception: tried to access method kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt.copyOfRange([Ljava/lang/Object;II)[Ljava/lang/Object; from class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:60)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:59)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:221)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:166)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:63)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinCompilerRunner.runCompiler(KotlinCompilerRunner.kt:133)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompiler(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:119)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:405)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:309)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:270)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt.copyOfRange([Ljava/lang/Object;II)[Ljava/lang/Object; from class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance.call(CallerImpl.kt:217)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:106)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KMutableProperty1Impl.set(KProperty1Impl.kt:59)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.arguments.ParseCommandLineArgumentsKt.updateField(parseCommandLineArguments.kt:187)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.arguments.ParseCommandLineArgumentsKt.parsePreprocessedCommandLineArguments(parseCommandLineArguments.kt:178)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.arguments.ParseCommandLineArgumentsKt.parseCommandLineArguments(parseCommandLineArguments.kt:66)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:49)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:39)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:202)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:194)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:350)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
```

I'm using this configuration:

```
Build gradle: 3.3.0 
Android Studio 3.3
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0
```

I'm not understand why this happens, I had search on internet but nothing helps..

**UPDATE:**

Output of `dependencies`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

kotlinCompilerClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.11
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11 -> 1.1.3-2
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.11
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.11
          \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11 -> 1.1.3-2 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the compiler uses incorrect version of the standard library to run itself.

Run the Gradle task `dependencies` with `--configuration kotlinCompilerClasspath` argument in the subproject where build fails to diagnose what causes that incorrect version getting in the compiler classpath:

```
./gradlew dependencies --configuration kotlinCompilerClasspath
```

The correct output should look like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :examples/kotlin
------------------------------------------------------------

kotlinCompilerClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.11
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.11
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.11
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.11
          \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Comment: I've updated the post with my output, the only differents which I see is on stdlib, it is that the problem?

Comment: I'm very stupid, now I see that in my build.gradle there is a line on `resolutionStrategy.force` that force to use kotlin stdlib 1.1.3-2, thanks for the tip!